# Weight consumed inside the on_idle hook?

Tags: pallet, weight, benchmarking, hook

[The documentation of the `on_idle` hook](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Hooks.html#method.on_idle) states that "Any implementation should always respect `_remaining_weight` and never consume (and therefore return) more than this amount."

In the contracts pallet, the implementation is as follows:

```rust
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_idle(_block: BlockNumberFor<T>, mut remaining_weight: Weight) -> Weight {
        use migration::MigrateResult::*;
        // ...

        ContractInfo::<T>::process_deletion_queue_batch(remaining_weight)
            .saturating_add(T::WeightInfo::on_process_deletion_queue_batch())
    }
}
```

Let's consider a scenario where `process_deletion_queue_batch` entirely consumes the `remaining_weight`. In this case, the return value of `on_idle` will exceed the authorized limit when adding the overhead weight `T::WeightInfo::on_process_deletion_queue_batch()`.

Intuitively, I would rather have done:

```rust
ContractInfo::<T>::process_deletion_queue_batch(remaining_weight.saturating_sub(T::WeightInfo::on_process_deletion_queue_batch()))
```

To ensure that the return value of `on_idle` never exceeds the `remaining_weight`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I was missing the `let base_weight = T::WeightInfo::on_process_deletion_queue_batch();` statement in the `deletion_budget(weight_limit: Weight)` function, which is called within the `process_deletion_queue_batch(weight_limit: Weight)` function. As a result, the returned weight will never exceed the `remaining_weight`.